# Building lxml on Windows using MinGW

Tags: python, c, mingw, lxml, distutils

My Python application required lxml. When I tried installing lxml, it the a "vcvrsall.bat not found" error. After digging around on the interwebs, I found that I needed to install MinGW, add it to my PATH variable and modify the distutils.cfg to use this compiler. It worked to the point that it now tried to download the lxml sources and compile it but fails on an error that reads `fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory`. It seems that lxml in turn depends on the libxml C library. How can I install this C library into my MinGW environment so that I can continue building my lxml.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that lxml in turn depends on the libxml C library.

`lxml` *is* a python wrapper for the `libxml` C library.

> How can I install this C library into my MinGW environment so that I can continue building my lxml.

Try this tutorial: http://www.pokorra.de/coding/compile_libxml_mingw.html

For lxml, you have to include references to the libxml headers and also have to link against the binaries.

Answer (score 1):

you can download Unofficial Windows Binaries at:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

e.g. for python 2.7 32bit:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/3i67tivk/lxml-2.3.3.win32-py2.7.exe